# WPF Listbox grouping

Tags: wpf, listbox, grouping

I need to display  in the list box like below. The scenario is it will have multiple groups followed by items with alignment horizontally.

```
    GroupA
      GroupA Description
    GroupB
      GroupB Description
    Items Available
     ItemA ItemB ITemC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
<Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding ....}" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
</Style>


<ListBox x:Name="lbPersonList" Margin="19,17,162,25" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Nota : adjust your binding on your code